# Error: Sizes do not match in connection - Sweptvolume and ClosedVolume -Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I try to a model in which when the pressure inside the `ClosedVolume` exceed a certain pressure level, then `HDVentile` opens and  the fluid flows into the `boundary1` component. I defined the nports=1 in `sweptvolume` and nPorts =2 in `ClosedVolume`. In this case it throws an error saying

> Sizes do not match in connection, size of 'ClosedVolume.ports' is [2] and size of 'Swept1.ports' is

If I set the nports=2 in `sweptvolume` and nPorts =2 in `ClosedVolume`, then it throws an error saying:

> Assertion failed:  each ports[i] of volume can at most be connected to one component. If two or more connections are present, ideal mixing takes place with these connections, which is usually not the intention of the modeller. Increase nPorts to add an additional port

Do you know how to handle this error? Thanks in advance!

```
model modelmitclosedvolume
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real N = 2800;
    replaceable package medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater( );
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Swept1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.000000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 2,
        use_portsData = false,
        p_start = 1e5,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system (p_ambient = 101325);
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = 46.66,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = -Modelica.Constants.pi/4);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe3 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        momentumDynamics = system.momentumDynamics,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        energyDynamics = system.energyDynamics,
        allowFlowReversal = system.allowFlowReversal,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile (dp_nominal = 95, m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe4 (
        length = 0.5,
        diameter = 0.03,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        momentumDynamics = system.momentumDynamics,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        energyDynamics = system.energyDynamics,
        allowFlowReversal = system.allowFlowReversal,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.a_vb);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1 (p = 500e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume (
        V = 0.005/6,
        nPorts = 2,
        portsData = {Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.001),Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.001)},
        redeclare package Medium = medium);


equation
    //Connection(s)
    connect(Posit1.flange, Swept1.flange);
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(pipe3.port_b, HDVentile.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile.port_b, pipe4.port_a);
    connect(pipe4.port_b, boundary1.ports[1]);
    connect(ClosedVolume.ports[1], pipe3.port_a);
    connect(ClosedVolume.ports, Swept1.ports);
end  modelmitclosedvolume;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the last connect should be

```
    connect(ClosedVolume.ports[2], Swept1.ports[1]);
```

and for `Swept1` it should be `nPorts = 1`.

If you then add an input to HDVentile e.g. using

```
    HDVentile.opening = 0;
```

the system should work.

Background: `nports` corresponds to the number of connections to the component. Then you usually only connect a single line to each port. Therefore you need two for the `ClosedVolume` and single one for `Swept1`.